# Cannot access hawkular metrics

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I have install openshift origin 3.9 using inventory file like you. I have used below line for metrics installation:

```
openshift_metrics_install_metrics=true
openshift_metrics_hawkuler_hostname=hawkular-metrics.example.com
openshift_master_metrics_public_url=https://hawkular-metrics.example.com/hawkular/metrics
```

And I installed using inventory file with prerequisites.yaml and then deploy_cluster.yaml, so that hawker-cassandra, hawkular-metrics and heapster in running condition and oc adm top node command is working.

But problem is cannot access hawkular metrics by below command:

```
curl -H "Athorization :Bearer XXXXX" -H "Hawkular-Tenant:openshift-infra" -X GET https://hawkular-metrics.example.com/hawkular/metrics/metics
```

Showing error:

> could not resolve host:hawkular-metrics.example.com,unknown error.

To deploy metrics and access metrics should I need any thing extra for this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `hawkular-metrics.example.com/hawkular/metrics/metics` accessible from client? Either a DNS Server or a local `/etc/hosts` entry should resolve `hawkular-metrics.example.com` to the node where router pod resides.

Comment: Now I am getting another issue in times of installation:TASK [openshift_hosted : Poll for OpenShift pod deployment success]            I think this error is for router pod installation..and other thing previously I was getting a error from web console"metrics not available error"from the pod of hawkular metrics

Comment: I have one master and two nodes.There are  router pods is running master and all nodes which ip address I need to provide correspond to hawkular-metrics.example.com  in /etc/hosts?

Comment: run `oc get pods -o wide -n default | grep router` to get ip address.

Comment: yes i have checked like that only and get single pod is running for router all node.so I have total three node three pod is running.can you help otherthing openshift_master_default_subdomain name need to store /etc/resolve.conf?

Comment: my error on webconsole is  Metrics are not available.

An error occurred getting metrics for container hawkular-cassandra-1 from https://hawkular-metrics.example.com/hawkular/metrics.

Comment: run `oc get pods -n openshift-infra` to check if cassandra is running. Also check cassandra logs if needed. `oc logs hawkular-cassandra-1 -n openshift-infra`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.now i am getting data on webconsole.but getting error through curl command:                                 curl -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Hawkular-Tenant: openshift-infra" -X GET https://hawkular-metrics.example.com/hawkular/metrics/metrics                                                                     error is:curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.

Comment: I need this data,it will be fine if I get the metrics data,other wise it is ok if i fetch data from cassendra database.